# QGIS Plugin - How to automatically add point cloud layers to QGIS at the end of a processing tool?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, pdal

I'm adding some tools in a plugin that handles point cloud layers.
At the end of a tool, I'd like that the project adds automatically the output point cloud layer created. I tried using QgsProcessingParameterPointCloudDestination but it gives me the following error :

> “.las” files are not supported as outputs for this algorithm

Am I using theses parameters the right way ?
Here is my code :

```
    INPUT_PCL = "INPUT_PCL"
    INPUT_POLYGONS = "INPUT_POLYGONS"
    OUTPUT_PCL = "OUTPUT_PCL"

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterPointCloudLayer(
                name=self.INPUT_PCL,
                description=self.tr("Input point cloud"),
            )
        )
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource
            (
                self.INPUT_POLYGONS,
                self.tr("Input polygons layer"),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon],
            )
        )
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination(
                name=self.OUTPUT_PCL,
                description=self.tr("Path of the output clipped point cloud file"),
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

        polygons_layer = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.INPUT_POLYGONS, context)
        pcl_layer = self.parameterAsPointCloudLayer(parameters, self.INPUT_PCL, context)
        pcl_string_out = self.parameterAsPointCloudLayer(parameters, self.OUTPUT_PCL, context)
        if pcl_string_out:
            output = clip(pcl_layer, polygons_layer, pcl_string_out.source())
        else:
            output = clip(pcl_layer, polygons_layer)
        return {"out_layer": output}
```

The following clip function is just a wrapper around a processing but it could be

```
def clip(input_layer: QgsPointCloudLayer, overlay: QgsVectorLayer,
         output_path: str = "TEMPORARY_OUTPUT") -> QgsPointCloudLayer:

    alg_name = "pdal:clip"
    params = {
        "INPUT": input_layer,
        "OUTPUT": output_path,
        "OVERLAY": overlay
    }
    output = processing.runAndLoadResults(alg_name, params)["OUTPUT"]
    return output
```

Comment: I can't find any info on the PDAL plugin. Can you provide a link?